# Registration form is not authenticate giving error 'MissingUsernameError'

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to add registration detail to database. If i was adding only username and password by this then i am able to insert in mongo db but i am trying to insert name, email all thing then they are giving `MissingUsernameError`.

```
{ 
  firstName: 'Name',
  lastName: 'Last',
  email: 'abc@gmail.com',
  phone: '1111111111',
  password: 'password' 
}
```

> {
>       MissingUsernameError: No username was given
>       at Promise.resolve.then (C:\Users\Music\web\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:231:17)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name:
>   'MissingUsernameError',   message: 'No username was given'  }

```js
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var newUser = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone
  });
  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.render("register");
    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
      res.redirect("/");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please share user schema ?

Comment: Maybe your schema will have `username` field as mandatory

Comment: `var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName : String,
 lastName : String,
 email : String,
 phone : Number,
 password : String
});`

Comment: This is my schema